# Shibboleth 2.5 on IIS - Handler invoked at an unconfigured location

Tags: shibboleth

Hoping for some assistance with Shibboleth auth services. Shib supports running multiple IIS sites but I'm having problems getting a location setup.  It's a sea of XML options so some pointer (on matching Ids??) would be greatly appreciated.

In my implementation, http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status  works but this does not:  http://staging.sphsc.washington.edu/Shibboleth.sso/Metdata

The relevant XML from shibboleth2.xml is:

```
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">

        <Site id="1" name="localhost" />
        <Site id="288954588" name="staging.sphsc.washington.edu" />

    .... 

<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="localhost">
            <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
        </Host>
        <Host name="staging.sphsc.washington.edu" applicationId="sphsc_local_22">
            <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
        </Host>

    .... 

<ApplicationDefaults entityID="http://staging.sphsc.washington.edu/shibboleth"
        REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
        signing="false" encryption="false">


    <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem"
        checkAddress="false" handlerSSL="false" cookieProps="http">

        <SSO isDefault="true" entityID="urn:mace:incommon:washington.edu">
            SAML2 SAML1
        </SSO>

        <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>

        <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false" />
        <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1" />
        <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false" />
        <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed" />


    .... 
    <ApplicationOverride id="sphsc_local_22" entityID="http://staging.sphsc.washington.edu/shibboleth" />
    ....
```